# PHP: Cannot redeclare function error?

Tags: php

```
<?php  
function date($x) {
    $contents = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $contents = file("$contents");
    $date = $contents[$x][6].$contents[$x][7]
        ."-".$contents[$x][8].$contents[$x][9]
        ."-"."20".$contents[$x][4].$contents[$x][5];
    return $date;
}
?>
```

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare date() in .../includes.php on line 20

I have created several functions with the same exact structure as the one above and they work fine. For some reason this function keeps returning this error. Any suggestions/solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated!

thx,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHP already has a `date()` function and you cannot overwrite existing functions in this language. Rename your function and it will work. Or wrap it in a class and it will work as well.

Answer (score 8):

date is an existing built-in function in PHP. You can not redeclare existing functions.
http://www.php.net/date

Answer (score 7):

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare x.php (previously declared in ...)

```
if (!function_exists('gule')) {
    function gule() {...}
}
```

---

I googled this because I could not redeclare function, as the .php file was included multiple times.
Though unrelated, somebody might get here looking for this answer because of topic. :]

Comment: I added this to my page and then get an error 1064 saying I have an error in `mySQL` syntax on line 1. Line 1 is where I put this code. Since for some reason my inc_pgtop.php is redeclaring the `timeOptions` function